# How does module.exports work

Tags: node.js

I'm using Express and Mongodb to write my first web app and this is probably a noob question, but let's say I were to define a user model in a file called users.js and then called `const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)` somewhere in the file.

Upon importing users.js (via `const User = require([path to users.js])` to some other file in the app, why can I then call `new User` and have access to the model instead of having to call `new users.User`?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to define the model and using the schema in the controller

User.js

```
 //User Model
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: String,
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    index: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true
  },
  mobile: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    index: true,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  profilePic: String,
  password: { type: String },
  locations: [{}],
  location: {
    type: { type: String, default: 'Point', enum: ['Point'] },
    coordinates: { type: [], default: [0, 0] },
    name: String,
    shortAddress: String
  },
  address: String,
  gender: String,
  dob: Date,
  signupType: { type: String, enum: ['facebook', 'google'] },
  deviceType: String,
  createdTime: Date,
  updatedTime: Date,
  googleToken: String,
  facebookToken: String,
  fcmToken: String,
  facebookLink: String,
  facebookId: String,
  memberType: String,
  deviceId: String,
  preferences: [{}],
  loginData: [{}],
  token:String,
  isVerified: Boolean,
  isMobileVerified: Boolean,
  isEmailVerified: Boolean,
  lastSeen: Date
});

// 2D sphere index for user location

userSchema.index({ location: '2dsphere' });

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User');
```

UserController.js

```
//User Controller 
var User = require('./User');


    // RETURNS ALL THE USERS IN THE DATABASE
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        User.find({}, function (err, users) {
            if (err) return res.status(500).send({ errors: "There was a problem finding the users." });
            res.status(200).send(users);
        });
    });
```

Comment: That's actually a really good model, and if you have a link for where that comes from so I can view the breakdown of what each field is, that'd be awesome. But I still have the question on why the user model becomes accessible across the entire app without having to call `[modulename].[model]`

Comment: It's a real-time project model that I'm working on so that was created by me

Comment: You can follow mongoose, nodejs documentation to create wonders

Comment: your question answer is the module.exports will make you  import the User model and accessible across entire app without having the call

Comment: Welcome, If you feel it is a good answer then you can upvote and make it correct that would save many developers time who are having the same query